# Какая разница между словосочетаниями "в последний раз" и "последний раз"?

Tags: предлоги

Скажите отличаются ли следующие предложения по значению.

> Я сегодня ем этот шоколад **последний раз**.
>
> Я сегодня ем этот шоколад **в последний раз**.

Answer (score 4):

Субъективно

Во фразе **`в последний раз`** есть коннотация приближающегося конца жизни, т.е. `в последний раз в жизни`, потому что больше уже не суждено.

В словосочетании **`последний раз`** без предлога такой коннотации нет.

---

**ОБНОВ.**

В двух советских фильмах обратил внимание на использование фразы с предлогом "**В**" в том же значении, что и без предлога.

Тем не менее, думаю, что с предлогом "**В**" фраза может приобретать значение последнего раза навсегда, в то время как без него она может значить последний раз только по состоянию на нынешний момент или на определённый период.
Но в вопросительном предложении такая разница не наблюдается.

Comment: Мне кажется,  связь с концом жизни несколько преувеличена.

Comment: нет ничего такого. "Когда в последний раз вы были в Италии?" и "Когда последний раз вы были в Италии?" смысл не меняется. "Он закурил в последний раз" и  "Он закурил последний раз" эмоциональную окраску диктует контекст.

Comment: @Crantisz пожалуй, я исходил из контекста, предложенного в вопросе, довольно сложно учесть всё многообразие случаев

Answer (score 2):

По моему мнению обе фразы означают одно и то же. Фраза с предлогом выстроена грамматически более строго: существительное, прилагательное и предлог выполняют свои классические роли.

Без предлога словосочетание *последний раз* начинает терять внутреннюю структуру и приобретать как единое целое наречное значение. Более отчетливо это видно в схожих по структуре выражениях: например, *второй раз* можно заменить на *вторично*, *повторно*.

Поэтому фраза без предлога звучит более разговорно, а с предлогом - более формально, и из-за этого, возможно, воспринимается некоторыми с  фатальным оттенком.

Comment: всё-таки формальность и фатальность - разные категории, тут всё решает статистика узуса

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Хотел пояснить свою логику: формально -> серьёзно -> серьезно в последний раз -> последний раз в жизни. Впрочем, я не настаиваю.

Answer (score 1):

Ситуации могут различаться:

1. Этот шоколад мне не нравится, больше не буду есть такой.
2. Мне не судьба ещё раз отведать этого шоколада: там, куда я направляюсь, его нет.

Формальное различие здесь в том, что *предлогом* "вписываются" во временной интервал события поедания шоколада (процесс мыслят в его протяжённости, возможно, смакуют). Без предлога на событие просто ссылаются как на факт.